# Why aren't my bold colors displaying properly?

Tags: 13.10, gnome-terminal, colors

I am trying to get solarized to work in the gnome-terminal, tmux, and vim. It has been a chore. Just when I thought I had them set up properly I noticed that my bold font colors aren't displaying correctly in Vim. This is a problem because the HTML bolds all tags.

So I started a hunt and came across:

https://superuser.com/questions/512138/urxvt-bold-colors-are-wrong-bold-0-7-are-using-colors-from-8-15

which explained that I need to change my `.Xresources` to

> URxvt.intensityStyles: false

Did that. Still no luck. I am not at my wit's end trying to get this to work. I was hoping somebody out there had an idea.

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. I am using the default gnome-terminal and have tried changing TERM: `xterm` and `xterm-256color`.

I used this simple bash script to check my results

https://gist.github.com/benizi/4173926

And here is a screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

GNOME Terminal version 3.28 (appearing in Ubuntu 18.04) introduces a new configuration option so that the bold attribute doesn’t change to the “bright” counterpart of the color.

[image: Show bold text in bright colors]